# IF statement to button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

been working on it for a couple days, building an automated pop can smasher...so.... the solenoid(using a relay just for simplicity), kicks on when started, stays on, but i can use my "stop" button to stop it, and my "start" button to start it again. i cant figure out how to include my "if" statement and "range(2) string to my "start" button, so say i run it 100 times and want to "stop" it at any given time.....then once i exit my window(widget) my "IF" statement executes the rest, my code is correct without any errors, just positioning problems ..maybe...thanks for all the help and info, it is greatly appreciated!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')      #size of window

class CanSmasher:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        myFont = font.Font(size=20)     #define Font

    self.printButton = Button(frame, text="Start", bg="green", fg="black", command = lambda: solenoid_off(21),width=20, height=5)
    self.printButton['font'] = myFont
    self.printButton.pack()

     self.quitButton = Button(frame, text ="Stop", bg="red", fg="black", command = lambda: solenoid_on(21), width=20, height=5)
    self.quitButton['font'] = myFont
    self.quitButton.pack()

channel = 21

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(channel, GPIO.OUT)

def solenoid_on(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.HIGH)   # Turn solenoid on
def solenoid_off(pin):
    GPIO.output(pin, GPIO.LOW)    # Turn solenoid off

c=CanSmasher(root)
root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        for i in range(2):        # Number of times ran is writen in ==> [range(put run times here)]

            solenoid_on(channel)
            time.sleep(1)         # Sets lag time

            solenoid_off(channel)
            time.sleep(1)         # Sets run time
        print("Cans Crushed", i+1)

        GPIO.cleanup()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Take a look at this SO post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). If you move the definitions of `root` and `c` into your if statement there it should start to work more how you want it to.

Comment: Do you want to keep turning solenoid on and off when you click the `Start` button, and stop the on/off of solenoid when you click the `Stop` button?

Comment: acw1668- no i do not, just wanna hit start, run my guesstimated range and let r' buck

Comment: Preston Hager - i  moved the root and c in every space and every indentation (when i got the error), and it did not work...

Comment: @clissolo: Read [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop)

Answer (score 0):

To start, look at the

```
self.quitButton = Button(frame, text ="Stop", bg="red", fg="black", command = lambda: solenoid_on(21), width=20, height=5)
```

Line. Pretty sure there is a 'space' too much. Maybe that happened while copy-pasting...just to make aware of it.

**I think moving:**

```
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')      #size of window

    c=CanSmasher(root)
    root.mainloop()`
```

into the "if-statement" should be the answer as stated in @Preston Hager's comment

Last Hint: Consider reading/following the python style-guide. That will make your code easier to use and read for other python-developers. 
For example, That would include changing `printButton` to `print_button` and the same for `quitButton`
[Python-Style-Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: sxeros - thank you for the input, it is definitely a mess not gonna lie, I'm kinda wishing there was a copy and paste method for this....didn't look for it i guess, but this was me researching, reading, watching videos and executing lol ....all within good time I'll get it figured out!!